# Outer join multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 4 table that I want to join:

```
tbl_transaksi_header
--------------------
kode_transaksi
kode_user
nama_penerima
email_penerima
alamat_penerima
bank
telpon


tbl_konfirmasi
--------------------
id
kode
member
namarekening

tbl_user
-------------------
kode_user
username_user

tbl_transaksi_detail
---------------------
kode_transaksi
harga
jumlah
status
```

I want to show all data including NULL in nama_rek.

I tried this:

```
SELECT t.status, t.kode_transaksi kode, u.username_user nama_user, t.nama_penerima penerima, t.telpon, t.bank, sum(d.harga*d.jumlah) total,k.namarekening nama_rek
FROM tbl_transaksi_header t
    JOIN tbl_user u
        ON t.kode_user=u.kode_user
    JOIN tbl_transaksi_detail d
        ON t.kode_transaksi=d.kode_transaksi
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_konfirmasi k
        ON t.kode_transaksi=k.kode
```

Work fine but not showing null result, only showing 1 row result. I want something like this:

```
status  kode    nama_user   penerima    telpn   bank    total   nama_rek
xxx     xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx     xxx     xxx     NULL
xxx     xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx     xxx     xxx     NULL
xxx     xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx     xxx     xxx     yyy
xxx     xxx     xxx         xxx         xxx     xxx     xxx     NULL
```

Sample data:

```
kode_transaksi  kode_user   nama_penerima   email_penerima  alamat_penerima bank    telpon
kd1             1           john            some@email.com  florida         Bank A  088833221
kd2             2           elsa            some@email.com  uk              Bank B  088833222
kd3             1           roy             some@email.com  manhattan       Bank C  088833223

id  kode    member  namarekening
1   kd1     paul    paul

kode_user   username_user
1           paul
2           elena

kode_transaksi  harga   jumlah  status
kd1             10      2       process
kd1             5       2       process
kd1             5       1       process
kd2             4       3       pending
kd2             3       4       pending
kd3             2       3       pending
```

I want this output:

```
status  kode    nama_user   penerima    telpon      bank    total   nama_rek
process kd1     paul        john        088833221   Bank A  35      paul
pending kd2     elena       elsa        088833222   Bank B  24      NULL
pending kd2     elena       roy         088833223   Bank C  6       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join is fine; the problem is that you have a `SUM()` in your select with no `GROUP BY`.  Try this:

```
SELECT  t.kode_transaksi kode, u.username_user nama_user, t.nama_penerima penerima, t.telpon, t.bank, sum(d.harga*d.jumlah) total,k.namarekening nama_rek
FROM tbl_transaksi_header t
    JOIN tbl_user u
        ON t.kode_user=u.kode_user
    JOIN tbl_transaksi_detail d
        ON t.kode_transaksi=d.kode_transaksi
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_konfirmasi k
        ON t.kode_transaksi=k.kode
GROUP BY
    t.kode_transaksi, u.username_user, t.nama_penerima , t.telpon, t.bank,k.namarekening
```

Comment: works fine with GROUP BY t.kode_transaksi only. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah.... generally good practice to GROUP BY all fields that aren't aggregated.  Some RBDMSs will fail otherwise (which, to me, is better than allowing it).